# new Wp_Query() or pre_get_posts() to view ALL posts for custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have an archive-template file that shows all posts for custom post type personnel (called archive-personnel.php):

This is the begining of the file...

```
<?php 
get_header(); 

//Show all posts for this custom posttype (personnel)
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'personnel', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$personnel_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if (have_posts()) : while ($personnel_query->have_posts()) : $personnel_query->the_post();
```

This is working, but I know that I can use `pre_get_posts()` as well. But with `pre_get_posts()` - filter you have to check if it affects admin etc.

So my question is: **Does it really matter which alternative I use** or is just a matter of preference/taste?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### *Main* query versus *secondary* queries:

> Does it really matter which alternative I use or is just a matter of
>   preference/taste?

Yes , there is a real difference:

**1)** pre_get_posts is modifying the [main query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81695/what-is-main-query) (or all queries) versus adding a secondary query using WP_Query.

**2)** If you want paging to work on the secondary query, you usually have to make modifications to the [main query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81695/what-is-main-query).

By using the `pre_get_posts` hook you can modify all queries that are instances of `WP_Query()`, including the *main query*, which is an instance of `WP_Query()` and is present for every page request.

Remember that `get_posts()`  is a wrapper for `WP_Query()` and the filter is active when the `suppress_filters` attribute is set as `FALSE`.

When using `pre_get_posts` you usually want to target specific queries by using some [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). Here are few examples, you can use:

**a)** [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) to determine if the current query is the *main* query.

**b)** [`! is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) to prevent modifications to queries in the backend.

**c)** [`is_post_type_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) to target the post type archives.

When you add your custom `WP_Query()`, then you are adding extra queries in addition to the main query.

I usually go with the `pre_get_posts` action if I can, instead of adding a secondary query.

### Example:

If you want to modify the main query, for the archive of the custom post type `personnel`, you can try:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ){
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'personnel' ) ) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
  }
});
```

This is untested but you get the idea ;-)

### Further reading:

Hopefully the following links can give you more information regarding the difference:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76553/should-i-use-pre-get-posts-or-wp-query
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81695/what-is-main-query

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for good response and references! :-) +1 for that!