# Show latest posts from each custom post type with pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

**What I have**

---

On my front page I have managed to alter the main query on the front page to show my custom post types with "pre_get_posts" like this:

```
function custom_post_types_in_home_loop( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'member',  'press', 'calendar_event' ) );
    }

    return $query;

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_types_in_home_loop' );
```

**What I want**

---

The problem is that some post types have way more posts than others, so I want to show only 3 posts per post type to get a little variation in the loop.

**What I've tried**

---

With some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303743/new-wp-query-or-pre-get-posts-to-view-all-posts-for-custom-post-type/21305598#21305598) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72780) answer ive managed to do this but nothing's happening, what am I doing wrong?

```
function custom_post_types_in_home_loop( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'member',  'press', 'calendar_event' ) );

        if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'member' ) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page',  3);
        }

        /* And the same 'if' statement for 'press' and 'calendar_event' */
    }

    return $query;

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_types_in_home_loop' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `post_type` on the main query to an `array`. And then comparing it against a `string`. None of these conditionals are true and hence aren't executing.

If you simply want to limit the number of queries and pick a random order you can do so with,

```
$query->set('posts_per_page', 9);
$query->set('orderby', 'rand);
```

This will give you 9 posts, 3 each, randomly choosen between the different Custom Post Types.

To keep the different types together, you'll need to build a more complex and resource intensive `groupby` query. If you need this, I'd suggest building 3 different Custom Loops for each `post_type` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and now I see my error with the array/string comparison, and that obviously doesnt work.. I managed to solve the problem with another approach with help from this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71582